# How to check if a division with bcdiv() will produce a finite result?

Tags: php, math, numbers, decimal, bc

I'm building a class for working with arbitrary precision decimal numbers in PHP, using the [BCMath library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) internally.

When [adding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php), [subtracting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcsub.php), or [multiplying](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php) two numbers, it is possible to forecast the required precision to be sure not to lose any digit.

However when it comes to [division](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php), the number of digits can be infinite, and I'd like my library to throw an exception if the result of the division cannot be represented as a finite number of digits.

**How can I know, before dividing, if the result will be finite, and in that case, compute the scale of the result?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform `%` (modulus) operation... wait. Oh, SH...

**Actually it is not possible w/o performing division (or similar steps) itself.**

I may advice you to create a `divmod` function, which will return result of integer division (i.e. rounded down) and remainder. And check the remainder is equal to zero.

Also any [rational number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) may be represented as [repeating decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal), like `1/3 = 0.(3)` and `1/7 = 0.(142857)`. The bad part is that period length may be up to value of this number, hence it's better to represent number as `n/m` internally if one wants to perform exact calculations with rational numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A reduced fraction has a finite decimal representation if the only prime factors of the denominator are 2 and 5.

Using BCMath, I guess you'd have to implement the Euclidean algorithm for reducing a fraction to lowest terms and then test the denominator. It does not seem worth the trouble.